# Handling Stop Debugging button and Detach All button in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins

[DebuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debuggereventsclass.onenterdesignmode?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) is useful when Visual Studio stops debugging. 
OnEnterDesignMode gives [dbgEventReasonEndProgram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/dotnet/api/envdte.dbgeventreason?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) when a user presses Stop Debugging button.

However, OnEnterDesignMode also gives dbgEventReasonEndProgram (not dbgEventReasonDetachProgram) when a user presses Detach All button.

How can I distinguish Stop Debugging from Detach All command in my Visual Studio Extension (.vsix)?

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853341/in-a-visual-studio-extension-how-to-detect-when-the-debugger-continues).

Comment: You can monitor commands execution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865333/how-do-i-know-from-my-vsix-that-a-build-will-be-followed-by-a-debug-session